# Authentication for Mobile Devices

Tags: authentication, mobile, active-directory, wcf

I am looking for ways to Authenticate on a mobile device.

The mobile application is connecting to a WCF Service which in turn connects to a Database. Before the application retrieves any information from the WCF Service I will need it to authenticate against a different server which would use AD Records to confirm the access.

I have found the following [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994y9ec2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and a previous [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584198/authentication-service-using-wcf) but these are both outdated.

If anyone has a more up to date source of information or is able to provide some I would be more then grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like more of a web-programming question than security  question, but my answer is that you would do it similarly to any other authentication request, namely with a username and password as part of the initial web request. You could follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588691/user-authentication-for-mobile-clients-in-restful-wcf-4-service) on c# mobile authentication, specifically in the context of RESTful services (the answer seems to give starting points for multiple methods though, one of which should be suitable for your application) as a start.